# How to implement REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey

Tags: java, rest, authentication, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm looking for a way to enable token-based authentication in Jersey. I am trying not to use any particular framework. Is that possible?

My plan is: A user signs up for my web service, my web service generates a token, sends it to the client, and the client will retain it. Then the client, for each request, will send the token instead of username and password.

I was thinking of using a custom filter for each request and `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE')")`, but I just thought that this causes a lot of requests to the database to check if the token is valid.

Or not create filter and in each request put a param token? So that each API first checks the token and after executes something to retrieve resource.

Answer (score 1551, accepted):

### How token-based authentication works

In token-based authentication, the client exchanges *hard credentials* (such as username and password) for a piece of data called *token*. For each request, instead of sending the hard credentials, the client will send the token to the server to perform authentication and then authorization.

In a few words, an authentication scheme based on tokens follow these steps:

1. The client sends their credentials (username and password) to the server.
2. The server authenticates the credentials and, if they are valid, generate a token for the user.
3. The server stores the previously generated token in some storage along with the user identifier and an expiration date.
4. The server sends the generated token to the client.
5. The client sends the token to the server in each request.
6. The server, in each request, extracts the token from the incoming request. With the token, the server looks up the user details to perform authentication.

   - If the token is valid, the server accepts the request.
   - If the token is invalid, the server refuses the request.
7. Once the authentication has been performed, the server performs authorization.
8. The server can provide an endpoint to refresh tokens.

### What you can do with JAX-RS 2.0 (Jersey, RESTEasy and Apache CXF)

This solution uses only the JAX-RS 2.0 API, *avoiding any vendor specific solution*. So, it should work with JAX-RS 2.0 implementations, such as [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/), [RESTEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) and [Apache CXF](https://cxf.apache.org/).

It is worthwhile to mention that if you are using token-based authentication, you are not relying on the standard Java EE web application security mechanisms offered by the servlet container and configurable via application's `web.xml` descriptor. It's a custom authentication.

#### Authenticating a user with their username and password and issuing a token

Create a JAX-RS resource method which receives and validates the credentials (username and password) and issue a token for the user:

```java
@Path("/authentication")
public class AuthenticationEndpoint {

    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response authenticateUser(@FormParam("username") String username, 
                                     @FormParam("password") String password) {

        try {

            // Authenticate the user using the credentials provided
            authenticate(username, password);

            // Issue a token for the user
            String token = issueToken(username);

            // Return the token on the response
            return Response.ok(token).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build();
        }      
    }

    private void authenticate(String username, String password) throws Exception {
        // Authenticate against a database, LDAP, file or whatever
        // Throw an Exception if the credentials are invalid
    }

    private String issueToken(String username) {
        // Issue a token (can be a random String persisted to a database or a JWT token)
        // The issued token must be associated to a user
        // Return the issued token
    }
}
```

If any exceptions are thrown when validating the credentials, a response with the status `403` (Forbidden) will be returned.

If the credentials are successfully validated, a response with the status `200` (OK) will be returned and the issued token will be sent to the client in the response payload. The client must send the token to the server in every request.

When consuming `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, the client must send the credentials in the following format in the request payload:

```
username=admin&password=123456
```

Instead of form params, it's possible to wrap the username and the password into a class:

```java
public class Credentials implements Serializable {

    private String username;
    private String password;
    
    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

And then consume it as JSON:

```java
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response authenticateUser(Credentials credentials) {

    String username = credentials.getUsername();
    String password = credentials.getPassword();
    
    // Authenticate the user, issue a token and return a response
}
```

Using this approach, the client must to send the credentials in the following format in the payload of the request:

```json
{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "123456"
}
```

#### Extracting the token from the request and validating it

The client should send the token in the standard HTTP `Authorization` header of the request. For example:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token-goes-here>
```

The name of the standard HTTP header is unfortunate because it carries *authentication* information, not *authorization*. However, it's the standard HTTP header for sending credentials to the server.

JAX-RS provides [`@NameBinding`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/NameBinding.html), a meta-annotation used to create other annotations to bind filters and interceptors to resource classes and methods. Define a `@Secured` annotation as following:

```java
@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Secured { }
```

The above defined name-binding annotation will be used to decorate a filter class, which implements [`ContainerRequestFilter`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html), allowing you to intercept the request before it be handled by a resource method. The [`ContainerRequestContext`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html) can be used to access the HTTP request headers and then extract the token:

```java
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final String REALM = "example";
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "Bearer";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        // Get the Authorization header from the request
        String authorizationHeader =
                requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        // Validate the Authorization header
        if (!isTokenBasedAuthentication(authorizationHeader)) {
            abortWithUnauthorized(requestContext);
            return;
        }

        // Extract the token from the Authorization header
        String token = authorizationHeader
                            .substring(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME.length()).trim();

        try {

            // Validate the token
            validateToken(token);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            abortWithUnauthorized(requestContext);
        }
    }

    private boolean isTokenBasedAuthentication(String authorizationHeader) {

        // Check if the Authorization header is valid
        // It must not be null and must be prefixed with "Bearer" plus a whitespace
        // The authentication scheme comparison must be case-insensitive
        return authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.toLowerCase()
                    .startsWith(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME.toLowerCase() + " ");
    }

    private void abortWithUnauthorized(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        // Abort the filter chain with a 401 status code response
        // The WWW-Authenticate header is sent along with the response
        requestContext.abortWith(
                Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                        .header(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, 
                                AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME + " realm=\"" + REALM + "\"")
                        .build());
    }

    private void validateToken(String token) throws Exception {
        // Check if the token was issued by the server and if it's not expired
        // Throw an Exception if the token is invalid
    }
}
```

If any problems happen during the token validation, a response with the status `401` (Unauthorized) will be returned. Otherwise the request will proceed to a resource method.

#### Securing your REST endpoints

To bind the authentication filter to resource methods or resource classes, annotate them with the `@Secured` annotation created above. For the methods and/or classes that are annotated, the filter will be executed. It means that such endpoints will *only* be reached if the request is performed with a valid token.

If some methods or classes do not need authentication, simply do not annotate them:

```java
@Path("/example")
public class ExampleResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response myUnsecuredMethod(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        // This method is not annotated with @Secured
        // The authentication filter won't be executed before invoking this method
        ...
    }

    @DELETE
    @Secured
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response mySecuredMethod(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        // This method is annotated with @Secured
        // The authentication filter will be executed before invoking this method
        // The HTTP request must be performed with a valid token
        ...
    }
}
```

In the example shown above, the filter will be executed *only* for the `mySecuredMethod(Long)` method because it's annotated with `@Secured`.

### Identifying the current user

It's very likely that you will need to know the user who is performing the request agains your REST API. The following approaches can be used to achieve it:

#### Overriding the security context of the current request

Within your [`ContainerRequestFilter.filter(ContainerRequestContext)`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html#filter-javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext-) method, a new [`SecurityContext`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) instance can be set for the current request. Then override the [`SecurityContext.getUserPrincipal()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html#getUserPrincipal--), returning a [`Principal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html) instance:

```java
final SecurityContext currentSecurityContext = requestContext.getSecurityContext();
requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {

        @Override
        public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
            return () -> username;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure() {
        return currentSecurityContext.isSecure();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME;
    }
});
```

Use the token to look up the user identifier (username), which will be the [`Principal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html)'s name.

Inject the [`SecurityContext`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) in any JAX-RS resource class:

```java
@Context
SecurityContext securityContext;
```

The same can be done in a JAX-RS resource method:

```java
@GET
@Secured
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response myMethod(@PathParam("id") Long id, 
                         @Context SecurityContext securityContext) {
    ...
}
```

And then get the [`Principal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html):

```java
Principal principal = securityContext.getUserPrincipal();
String username = principal.getName();
```

#### Using CDI (Context and Dependency Injection)

If, for some reason, you don't want to override the [`SecurityContext`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html), you can use CDI (Context and Dependency Injection), which provides useful features such as events and producers.

Create a CDI qualifier:

```java
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER })
public @interface AuthenticatedUser { }
```

In your `AuthenticationFilter` created above, inject an [`Event`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/10/api/javax/enterprise/event/Event.html) annotated with `@AuthenticatedUser`:

```java
@Inject
@AuthenticatedUser
Event<String> userAuthenticatedEvent;
```

If the authentication succeeds, fire the event passing the username as parameter (remember, the token is issued for a user and the token will be used to look up the user identifier):

```java
userAuthenticatedEvent.fire(username);
```

It's very likely that there's a class that represents a user in your application. Let's call this class `User`.

Create a CDI bean to handle the authentication event, find a `User` instance with the correspondent username and assign it to the `authenticatedUser` producer field:

```java
@RequestScoped
public class AuthenticatedUserProducer {

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    @AuthenticatedUser
    private User authenticatedUser;
    
    public void handleAuthenticationEvent(@Observes @AuthenticatedUser String username) {
        this.authenticatedUser = findUser(username);
    }

    private User findUser(String username) {
        // Hit the the database or a service to find a user by its username and return it
        // Return the User instance
    }
}
```

The `authenticatedUser` field produces a `User` instance that can be injected into container managed beans, such as JAX-RS services, CDI beans, servlets and EJBs. Use the following piece of code to inject a `User` instance (in fact, it's a CDI proxy):

```java
@Inject
@AuthenticatedUser
User authenticatedUser;
```

Note that the CDI [`@Produces`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/inject/Produces.html) annotation is *different* from the JAX-RS [`@Produces`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html) annotation:

- CDI: [`javax.enterprise.inject.Produces`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/inject/Produces.html)
- JAX-RS: [`javax.ws.rs.Produces`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html)

Be sure you use the CDI [`@Produces`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/inject/Produces.html) annotation in your `AuthenticatedUserProducer` bean.

The key here is the bean annotated with [`@RequestScoped`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html), allowing you to share data between filters and your beans. If you don't wan't to use events, you can modify the filter to store the authenticated user in a request scoped bean and then read it from your JAX-RS resource classes.

Compared to the approach that overrides the [`SecurityContext`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html), the CDI approach allows you to get the authenticated user from beans other than JAX-RS resources and providers.

### Supporting role-based authorization

Please refer to my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814178/1426227) for details on how to support role-based authorization.

### Issuing tokens

A token can be:

- **Opaque:** Reveals no details other than the value itself (like a random string)
- **Self-contained:** Contains details about the token itself (like JWT).

See details below:

#### Random string as token

A token can be issued by generating a random string and persisting it to a database along with the user identifier and an expiration date. A good example of how to generate a random string in Java can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41156/1426227). You also could use:

```java
Random random = new SecureRandom();
String token = new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
```

#### JWT (JSON Web Token)

JWT (JSON Web Token) is a standard method for representing claims securely between two parties and is defined by the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519).

It's a self-contained token and it enables you to store details in *claims*. These claims are stored in the token payload which is a JSON encoded as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). Here are some claims registered in the [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) and what they mean (read the full RFC for further details):

- [`iss`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.1): Principal that issued the token.
- [`sub`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.2): Principal that is the subject of the JWT.
- [`exp`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.4): Expiration date for the token.
- [`nbf`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.5): Time on which the token will start to be accepted for processing.
- [`iat`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.6): Time on which the token was issued.
- [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7): Unique identifier for the token.

Be aware that you must not store sensitive data, such as passwords, in the token.

The payload can be read by the client and the integrity of the token can be easily checked by verifying its signature on the server. The signature is what prevents the token from being tampered with.

You won't need to persist JWT tokens if you don't need to track them. Althought, by persisting the tokens, you will have the possibility of invalidating and revoking the access of them. To keep the track of JWT tokens, instead of persisting the whole token on the server, you could persist the token identifier ([`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim) along with some other details such as the user you issued the token for, the expiration date, etc.

When persisting tokens, always consider removing the old ones in order to prevent your database from growing indefinitely.

### Using JWT

There are a few Java libraries to issue and validate JWT tokens such as:

- [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt)
- [java-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt)
- [jose4j](https://bitbucket.org/b_c/jose4j/wiki/Home)

To find some other great resources to work with JWT, have a look at [http://jwt.io](http://jwt.io/).

#### Handling token revocation with JWT

If you want to revoke tokens, you must keep the track of them. You don't need to store the whole token on server side, store only the token identifier (that must be unique) and some metadata if you need. For the token identifier you could use [UUID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4122).

The [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim should be used to store the token identifier on the token. When validating the token, ensure that it has not been revoked by checking the value of the [`jti`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.7) claim against the token identifiers you have on server side.

For security purposes, revoke all the tokens for a user when they change their password.

### Additional information

- It doesn't matter which type of authentication you decide to use. **Always** do it on the top of a HTTPS connection to prevent the [man-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).
- Take a look at [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/19676) from Information Security for more information about tokens.
- [In this article](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/) you will find some useful information about token-based authentication.

Comment: `The server stores the previously generated token in some storage along with the user identifier and an expiration date.

The server sends the generated token to the client.`

How is this RESTful?

Comment: @scottyseus Token based authentication works by how the server remembers the token it has issued. You can use JWT tokens for stateless authentication.

Comment: What about sending hashed password instead of plain (hashed with server-generated nonce)? Does it increase security level (for example when not using https)? In case of man in the middle - he will be able to hijack the one session, but at least he will not get the password

Comment: I can't believe this isn't in the official documentation.

Comment: Don't you save token in the Session? Looks like Tokens are stored at Client Side? (JS)

Comment: @grep In REST, there's no such thing as session on server side. Consequently, the session state is managed on the client side.

Comment: @cassiomolin would you please mind to look at my question ? if you can suggest any solution for the same ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60111743/how-to-prevent-rest-web-service-authentication-with-stolen-token

Comment: @cassiomolin I wanna test your solution with jersey testing framework. I create an AbstractBinder for the dependencies but i still can't run it. The primitive injected members  can not be found. Do you have an advice about it?

Comment: I added the Secure interface and filter class but its not working

Comment: @cassiomolin Hello and thank You for the great answer!!! It has helped me a lot! I just would like to ask if there are any security flaws or downsides regarding security (not convenience) when using self-implemented jax-rs/jjwt/jBCrypt solution as in your own GitHub demo repository over using standard spring-boot/sprint-jersey/spring-security solution? I am only concerted if this clean and pretty solution is sufficient enough?

https://github.com/cassiomolin/jersey-jwt

Comment: This is great work! How would you check the token exactly (in `validateToken(String token)`? You say *check if token is issued ...*, but we would need some resource to check the token against, right? Can we inject some custom class for checking tokens against sessions in a DB?

Comment: Great answer but I'm just confused why anyone would use the `SecurityContext` approach instead of the CDI approach? It seems the CDI approach is better by providing the actual User bean and also is more flexible to be used outside of JAX-RS.

Answer (score 136):

> <sup>This answer is all about **authorization** and it is a complement of [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/1426227) about **authentication**</sup>
>
> <sup>**Why *another* answer?** I attempted to expand my previous answer by adding details on how to support JSR-250 annotations. However the original answer became the way *too long* and exceeded the [maximum length of 30,000 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/176447/278120). So I moved the whole authorization details to this answer, keeping the other answer focused on performing authentication and issuing tokens.</sup>

---

### Supporting role-based authorization with the `@Secured` annotation

Besides authentication flow shown in the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/1426227), role-based authorization can be supported in the REST endpoints.

Create an enumeration and define the roles according to your needs:

```java
public enum Role {
    ROLE_1,
    ROLE_2,
    ROLE_3
}
```

Change the `@Secured` name binding annotation created before to support roles:

```java
@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Secured {
    Role[] value() default {};
}
```

And then annotate the resource classes and methods with `@Secured` to perform the authorization. The method annotations will override the class annotations:

```java
@Path("/example")
@Secured({Role.ROLE_1})
public class ExampleResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response myMethod(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        // This method is not annotated with @Secured
        // But it's declared within a class annotated with @Secured({Role.ROLE_1})
        // So it only can be executed by the users who have the ROLE_1 role
        ...
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("{id}")    
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Secured({Role.ROLE_1, Role.ROLE_2})
    public Response myOtherMethod(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
        // This method is annotated with @Secured({Role.ROLE_1, Role.ROLE_2})
        // The method annotation overrides the class annotation
        // So it only can be executed by the users who have the ROLE_1 or ROLE_2 roles
        ...
    }
}
```

Create a filter with the [`AUTHORIZATION`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html#AUTHORIZATION) priority, which is executed after the [`AUTHENTICATION`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/Priorities.html#AUTHENTICATION) priority filter defined previously.

The [`ResourceInfo`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceInfo.html) can be used to get the resource [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) and resource [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) that will handle the request and then extract the `@Secured` annotations from them:

```java
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        // Get the resource class which matches with the requested URL
        // Extract the roles declared by it
        Class<?> resourceClass = resourceInfo.getResourceClass();
        List<Role> classRoles = extractRoles(resourceClass);

        // Get the resource method which matches with the requested URL
        // Extract the roles declared by it
        Method resourceMethod = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        List<Role> methodRoles = extractRoles(resourceMethod);

        try {

            // Check if the user is allowed to execute the method
            // The method annotations override the class annotations
            if (methodRoles.isEmpty()) {
                checkPermissions(classRoles);
            } else {
                checkPermissions(methodRoles);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            requestContext.abortWith(
                Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build());
        }
    }

    // Extract the roles from the annotated element
    private List<Role> extractRoles(AnnotatedElement annotatedElement) {
        if (annotatedElement == null) {
            return new ArrayList<Role>();
        } else {
            Secured secured = annotatedElement.getAnnotation(Secured.class);
            if (secured == null) {
                return new ArrayList<Role>();
            } else {
                Role[] allowedRoles = secured.value();
                return Arrays.asList(allowedRoles);
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkPermissions(List<Role> allowedRoles) throws Exception {
        // Check if the user contains one of the allowed roles
        // Throw an Exception if the user has not permission to execute the method
    }
}
```

If the user has no permission to execute the operation, the request is aborted with a `403` (Forbidden).

To know the user who is performing the request, see [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/1426227). You can get it from the [`SecurityContext`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html) (which should be already set in the [`ContainerRequestContext`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html#filter-javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext-)) or inject it using CDI, depending on the approach you go for.

If a `@Secured` annotation has no roles declared, you can assume all authenticated users can access that endpoint, disregarding the roles the users have.

### Supporting role-based authorization with JSR-250 annotations

Alternatively to defining the roles in the `@Secured` annotation as shown above, you could consider JSR-250 annotations such as [`@RolesAllowed`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html), [`@PermitAll`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/PermitAll.html) and [`@DenyAll`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/DenyAll.html).

JAX-RS doesn't support such annotations out-of-the-box, but it could be achieved with a filter. Here are a few considerations to keep in mind if you want to support all of them:

- [`@DenyAll`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/DenyAll.html) on the method takes precedence over [`@RolesAllowed`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) and [`@PermitAll`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/PermitAll.html) on the class.
- [`@RolesAllowed`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) on the method takes precedence over [`@PermitAll`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/PermitAll.html) on the class.
- [`@PermitAll`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/PermitAll.html) on the method takes precedence over [`@RolesAllowed`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) on the class.
- [`@DenyAll`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/DenyAll.html) can't be attached to classes.
- [`@RolesAllowed`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html) on the class takes precedence over [`@PermitAll`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/annotation/security/PermitAll.html) on the class.

So an authorization filter that checks JSR-250 annotations could be like:

```java
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        Method method = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();

        // @DenyAll on the method takes precedence over @RolesAllowed and @PermitAll
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(DenyAll.class)) {
            refuseRequest();
        }

        // @RolesAllowed on the method takes precedence over @PermitAll
        RolesAllowed rolesAllowed = method.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
        if (rolesAllowed != null) {
            performAuthorization(rolesAllowed.value(), requestContext);
            return;
        }

        // @PermitAll on the method takes precedence over @RolesAllowed on the class
        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class)) {
            // Do nothing
            return;
        }

        // @DenyAll can't be attached to classes

        // @RolesAllowed on the class takes precedence over @PermitAll on the class
        rolesAllowed = 
            resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
        if (rolesAllowed != null) {
            performAuthorization(rolesAllowed.value(), requestContext);
        }

        // @PermitAll on the class
        if (resourceInfo.getResourceClass().isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class)) {
            // Do nothing
            return;
        }

        // Authentication is required for non-annotated methods
        if (!isAuthenticated(requestContext)) {
            refuseRequest();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Perform authorization based on roles.
     *
     * @param rolesAllowed
     * @param requestContext
     */
    private void performAuthorization(String[] rolesAllowed, 
                                      ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {

        if (rolesAllowed.length > 0 && !isAuthenticated(requestContext)) {
            refuseRequest();
        }

        for (final String role : rolesAllowed) {
            if (requestContext.getSecurityContext().isUserInRole(role)) {
                return;
            }
        }

        refuseRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Check if the user is authenticated.
     *
     * @param requestContext
     * @return
     */
    private boolean isAuthenticated(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        // Return true if the user is authenticated or false otherwise
        // An implementation could be like:
        // return requestContext.getSecurityContext().getUserPrincipal() != null;
    }

    /**
     * Refuse the request.
     */
    private void refuseRequest() {
        throw new AccessDeniedException(
            "You don't have permissions to perform this action.");
    }
}
```

<sup>**Note:** The above implementation is based on the Jersey [`RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/core-server/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/filter/RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.java). If you use Jersey, you don't need to write your own filter, just use the existing implementation.</sup>

Comment: Is there any github repository with this elegant solution available?

Comment: @DanielFerreiraCastro Of course. Have a look [here](https://github.com/cassiomolin/jersey-jwt).

Comment: Is it there any good way to validate that a request is from an authorized user AND that user CAN change the data because he "owns" the data (e.g. so a hacker can't use his token to change the name of another user)? I know I can check at every endpoint if the `user_id` == `token.userId`, or something like it, but this is very repetitive.

Comment: @mFeinstein An answer for that would surely require more characters than I can type here in the comments. Just to give you some direction, you could look for **row level security**.

Comment: I can see a lot of topics on databases for when I search for row level security, I will open this as a new question then

Comment: @cassiomolin here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250719/best-practice-for-enabling-a-user-to-only-change-the-data-he-owns-on-jax-rs-and

Comment: Don't you save token in the Session? Looks like Tokens are stored at Client Side? (JS)

Comment: @cassiomolin Thanks for the brilliant explanation. I'm using your example and almost everything works fine. I've got one question though: How would I have an endpoint that is free to all, but for authorized users, returns different data. If I add `@Secured` to the method and call it without a token, I get a 401, if I remove `@Secured`, I can't get the user information using `securityContext.getUserPrincipal()`. Any suggestions?