# How to create a custom @RolesAllowed for java rest endpoint token authentication?

Tags: java, rest, authentication, authorization, jax-rs

I am trying to create a `@RolesAllowed` tag on my rest endpoints. I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey) example to create a custom authentication point but now need to extend this to allow for the `@RolesAllowed` tag to be used on token based authentication.

I have tried using PicketLink but couldn't get it to play nicely with my app and found that I can use my own custom strategies to tailor the situation to my application.

Comment: What JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Comment: I'm using Wildfly Resteasy.