# Pass data from ContainerRequestFilter to Resource

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy

I don't know how to pass object data from container request filter to any other resources, by using CDI, because I cannot get my data in the resource. Any idea?

```
@Provider
public class AuthFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Inject
    private SomeBean bean;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        bean.setData("test");
    }
}

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SomeBean
{
    private String data;

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }
}
```

And in my resource class I have the following:

```
@Inject
private SomeBean bean;

@GET
public Response someMethod() {
    return Response.ok(bean.getData()).build();
}
```

Comment: I am guessing but one approach is to use `@SessionScoped` or `@ApplicationScoped` bean so that on injection the data will still be available.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of *data* do you need to pass from a request filter to other resources?

Comment: For example the current user logged in and the current organization data. I don't use principal and jaas to authenticate user

Comment: This answer might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/1426227