# Jersey ContainerRequestFilter: Getting 404 after throwing 'abortWith' with status forbidden (403)

Tags: java, rest, httpresponse, jersey-2.0, restful-authentication

Jersey 2.22 API with token authentication + role based authorization (the way I secured the API is based on the accepted answer from this post: [Best practice for REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey) . It might be better to read it before trying to understand my question) :

here is my **web.xml**:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- LISTENERS -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseySpringServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>ca.toto.api.filters</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>ca.toto.api.restapi</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>ca.toto.api.filters.AuthenticationFilter;ca.toto.api.filters.AuthorizationFilter;com.toto.api.restapi.TaskRestService</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseySpringServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/filters/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseySpringServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restapi/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When I make a call to my *tasks* web service, the flow goes in the first filter (**AuthenticationFilter**) without any problem (*@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)*), validates my token, gets the user from the decoded token then registers it as the **Principal** then passes in the second filter, **AuthorizationFilter** (*@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)*) where I get the user from the security context, get his role then check if he has permission to make the call. If yes, exit the filter normally if no, use *javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext*.**abortWith** method to send a response with status 403:

```
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    ...
try {
        boolean isAllowed = false;
        // Check if the user is allowed to execute the method
        // The method annotations override the class annotations
        if (methodRoles.isEmpty()) {
            logger.info("Checking permissions on CLASS level");
            isAllowed = checkPermissions(classRoles);
        } else {
            logger.info("Checking permissions on METHOD level");
            isAllowed = checkPermissions(methodRoles);
        }

        // Throw an Exception if the user has not permission to execute the method
        if(isAllowed == false) {
            logger.warn("USER IS NOT ALLOWED TO COMPLETE THE REQUEST. ABORT.");
             requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build());
    }
```

When the user has the right role, the service is called and I get the correct response with correct info.
My problem is that when my variable *isAllowed* equals to false, I get a **404** instead of a **403** and I can't figure out why...

here is my **TaskRestService** service definition:

```
@Path("/tasks")
@Secured({RoleEnum.admin})
public class TaskRestService {
    ...
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Task> getTasks(@QueryParam("code") String code) {
... }
```

Comment: Try setting this init-param [`jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR) for Jersey to `true` and see what happens

Comment: thanks @peeskillet, it's now working correctly. Write it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set this Jersey init-param [`jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR) to `true`. Here's what it states in the Javadoc

> Whenever response status is 4xx or 5xx it is possible to choose between `sendError` or `setStatus` on container specific `Response` implementation. E.g. on servlet container Jersey can call `HttpServletResponse.setStatus(...)` or `HttpServletResponse.sendError(...)`.
>
> Calling `sendError(...)` method usually resets entity, response headers and provide error page for specified status code (e.g. servlet error-page configuration). However if you want to post-process response (e.g. by servlet filter) the only way to do it is calling `setStatus(...)` on container `Response` object.
>
> If property value is true the method `Response.setStatus(...)` is used over default `Response.sendError(...)`.
>
> Type of the property value is `boolean`. The default value is `false`.

So what happens is the error cause the container to try and send you to an error page, and when there is non configured, you get a 404. So when you set the property to `true`, it cause the use of `setStatus` rather then `sendError`

---

**NOTE:** If you are not using a web.xml, for a `ResourceConfig`, you can use the `property(property, value)` method. For an `Application` subclass, you can override `Map<String, Object> getProperties()`

```
public class MyApp extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApp() {
        property(ServletProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR, true);
    }
}

public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put("jersey.config.server.response.setStatusOverSendError", true);
        return props;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have saved my life. And made my 2 hour google search totally worth it.