# Token-based authentication in Jersey 1.x

Tags: jersey, access-token, java-5

I have a REST API implemented with the following technologies:

- Jersey 1.19 (JSR 311)
- Jackson
- Jettison
- Java 5
- Tomcat 7

Currently I implement *Basic Authentication* using a servlet filter but I need to implement token-based authentication.

How do I do that? What is the best tutorial?

Comment: This solution uses JAX-RS 2.0, but you can get some inspiration from it: [Best practice for REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/1426227)

Comment: Just be aware that [Tomcat 7 supports Java 6 and later](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html).

Comment: work :D thanks people