# Best way to secure the communication between front-end and back-end

Tags: security

For a schoolproject my project group and I are splitting the front-end from the back-end of an application. Now I want to make sure the security of this application is figured out correctly as it is going to be publicly used.

I'm already looking into a SSL certificate, but I want to be secure as possible.

As for now I have created the log in page as following:

front-end is basic html, javascript with angularjs, once the user filled in their username and password and pressed login, I send the data in JSON through post to my backend

```
$scope.sendPost = function() {
    var jsontext = JSON.stringify({
        username: $scope.username,
        password: $scope.password
    });
    $http.post("http://localhost:8080/login", jsontext).success(function(data, status) {
       $scope.user = data;
    })    
}
```

and on the back-end I have a servlet set up using jersey that handles it and sends back the needed userdata

```
@POST
@Path("login")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String validateLogin(Request request) throws JSONException{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    // validate user blabla
    return json.toString();
}
```

I was wondering if this is secure enough and ways that would make the communication more secure

Comment: HTTPS is you best friend. Just in case you are interested in token based authentication, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/1426227) might be useful for you. For sure you can adapt it to work with basic authentication, which is much simpler.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for regarding security using tokens. I knew some, but didnt know how exactly. Thank you @CássioMazzochiMolin

Answer (score 1):

Term "secure front-back communication" includes a lot of stuff, and with `HTTPS` you are addressing just encryption, but missing sanitation, authentication, serialization, etc.

- Encryption: `HTTPS` is just one of the items a web application dev
  should issue if security is a concern. It encrypts communication
  between http client and server (excluding first ever handshake). A
  SSL certificate will handle this as you stated.
- [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRF) : In your case, servlet filters
  should be implemented to prevent it. Basically, it involves adding an
  additional header (`X-CSRF`) to all requests from client. For Jersey
  implementation check [CsrfProtectionFilter](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/jersey-server/src/main/java/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/CsrfProtectionFilter.java?rev=5392)
- Input Sanitation: Remove unwanted characters from form inputs, or
  request values that could make server misinterpret them leading to
  unwanted behaviour.  In your case, it could be implemented in
  `validateLogin` function.

Little plus: [OWASP top 10](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) lists most common web application attack vectors, check it out!