# How to use CDI Events in Java Jersey?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, glassfish, cdi

I am trying to follow this post's upvoted answer: [Best practice for REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey)

I'm using the CDI approach and in my filter i have the definition:

```
@Inject
@AuthenticatedUser
Event<String> userAuthenticatedEvent;
```

But, when I run tomcat 7, I get the following error:

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=Event<String>,parent=AuthenticationFilter,qualifiers={@com.wink.rest.security.annotation.AuthenticatedUser()},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,567185196)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:75)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justInject(Utilities.java:945)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.inject(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:979)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanHk2Factory$2.getInstance(AbstractCdiBeanHk2Factory.java:142)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.AbstractCdiBeanHk2Factory._provide(AbstractCdiBeanHk2Factory.java:91)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.ext.cdi1x.internal.GenericCdiBeanHk2Factory.provide(GenericCdiBeanHk2Factory.java:63)
```

I have tried everything I found on google and stackoverflow to try to resolve this, but none of the solutions worked. So now I'm not sure what else to do. Anyone have any advice?

Comment: You say you're running on tomcat.  What CDI runtime are you using?

Comment: You may also want to look into hk2 events: https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b03/events.html

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with the same exact issue I found a solution to that. I switched from TomCat to Glassfish and updated maven dependencies to match the ones from  [official Jersey 2 documentation](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/modules-and-dependencies.html). After that it worked like magic.