# JAX-RS Authentication Filter is not triggered via @Secured annotation

Tags: java, rest, web-services, authentication, jax-rs

I am following this answer: [Best practice for REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/4802797) to implement the REST API authentication.   But the JAX-RS Authentication Filter is not triggered via @Secured annotation.

I finished until the part **Securing your REST endpoints** by adding `@Secured` on the method.

This is how I am doing this.

### Secured.java

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({TYPE, METHOD})
public @interface Secured { }
```

### AuthenticationFilter.java

```
@Secured
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "Bearer";

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        // Get the Authorization header from the request
        String authorizationHeader = requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);

        // Validate the Authorization header
        if (!isTokenBasedAuthentication(authorizationHeader)) {
            abortWithUnauthorized(requestContext);
            return;
        }

        // Extract the token from the Authorization header
        String token = authorizationHeader.substring(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME.length()).trim();

        try {
            validateToken(token);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            abortWithUnauthorized(requestContext);
        }
    }

    private boolean isTokenBasedAuthentication(String authorizationHeader) {
        // Check if the Authorization header is valid
        // It must not be null and must be prefixed with "Bearer" plus a whitespace
        // Authentication scheme comparison must be case-insensitive
        return (authorizationHeader != null &&
            authorizationHeader.toLowerCase().startsWith(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME.toLowerCase() + " "));
    }

    private void abortWithUnauthorized(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        // Abort the filter chain with a 401 status code
        // The "WWW-Authenticate" is sent along with the response
        requestContext.abortWith(
                Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.WWW_AUTHENTICATE, AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME)
                    .build());
    }

    private void validateToken(String token) throws Exception {
        // Check if it was issued by the server and if it's not expired
        // Throw an Exception if the token is invalid
    }
```

### MyApis.java

```
@Path("api")
public class MyApis {

    @GET
    @Secured
    @Path("me")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map<String, X500Name> whoAmI() {
        return ImmutableMap.of("me", legalName);
    }

    // other APIs
}
```

When I call `/api/me`, I can get the response directly without any authentication header provided.   It seems like the filter is not triggered or not registered properly.

I have seen this question [JAX RS, my filter is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679654/jax-rs-my-filter-is-not-working), but it does not solve my problem.

And how I understand the following is that `web.xml` is not needed right?

> This solution uses only the JAX-RS 2.0 API, avoiding any vendor specific solution. So, it should work with the most popular JAX-RS 2.0 implementations, such as Jersey, RESTEasy and Apache CXF.
>
> It's important mention that if you are using a token-based authentication, you are not relying on the standard Java EE web application security mechanisms offered by the servlet container and configurable via application's web.xml descriptor.

Answer (score 1):

Late for answer, but the solution to this problem is to add AuthenticationFilter to your classes.

`public class App extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(MyApis.class);
        classes.add(AuthenticationFilter.class);
        return classes;
    }
}`