# Unable to make working ContainerRequestFilter

Tags: java, rest, endpoint

I am trying for several hours to make working the mechanism explained in topic: [Best practice for REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey/39318843#39318843)

But after debugging it seems that I am not stopping in the ContainerRequestFilter...
Here is what I have:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;

@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Secured { }
```

My AuthenticationFilter is exactly the same as what is explained in the topic (copy past)

I have an endpoint:

```
  @Path("/")
  @WebService(name="account", targetNamespace="")
  public interface ProfileCXFService
  {
  @GET
  @Secured
  @Path("/displayProfile")
  @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
  public Response displayProfile(@QueryParam("token")String token, @QueryParam("profileID")String profileID);
  }
```

And here is the content of my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<display-name>CxfRestService</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Here is the request I am sending with postman (For the moment the token is inside the body but even If I put it in the Authentication header param it is not working). The problem is that code of the endpoint is directly executed and nothing the Filter is not called.

```
GET /BD-BD/rest/account/displayProfile?token=vfE1qPLiiyPx20ymp0C483VxcpCj07HKAB8cTmgXamp;profileID=35 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 0908ac3d-17ab-55ef-337a-fabfe7fed387
```

Is there a configuration needed??
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

When using Apache CXF, the filters and interceptors must be registered in the `cxf.xml` configuration file. This file must be in the classpath of your application.

Here's an example extracted from the [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-filters.html) of what your CXF configuration file can be like when registering a filter:

```xml
<beans>
    <jaxrs:server id="customerService" address="/">

        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
          <bean class="org.CustomerService" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>

        <jaxrs:providers>
          <ref bean="authorizationFilter" />
        </jaxrs:providers>

        <bean id="authorizationFilter" class="com.bar.providers.AuthorizationFilter">
            <!-- authorization bean properties -->
        </bean>

    </jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

For more details, check the [CXF documentation about configuration](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/configuration.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot !!  I will have a look !

Comment: Tomorrow morning I will let you know :)

Comment: WORKING!! In fact I declared it the filter in my web.xml :) Thanks a lot man!

Comment: @Geoffrey I'm glad to know that. If my answer was useful in any way, please consider clicking the upvote button :)

Comment: Done. Sorry I am beginner on this site  :)