# Where can I define the users who follow a role?

Tags: java, jersey

I am using `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature` as defined in https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html#annotation-based-security example 16.5 and 16.6

I register it as this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/demo")
public class App extends ResourceConfig {
    public App() {
        this.packages("com.bla bla bla package");
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    }
}
```

And then in the Java class I do this:

```
@Path("request")
@RolesAllowed({ "admin", "thirdPartyDeveloper" })
public class DemoService {
}
```

My question is where to state the users who belong to the **admin** role and the users who belong to the **third party developer** role?

Where can I set their credentials?

Comment: It use the Interface SecurityContext to find user / role, so you can find implementation in a Java EE server or in Spring Security (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5/)

Comment: Thank you but I am not using Spring

Comment: Ok what application server you used ? If it's a Java EE server you'll find in it's documentation how to configure securityContext. If tomcat I think you need to find a external implementation (maybe spring security or http://picketbox.jboss.org).

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque that is the thing, the security context, but where/and how should I define it. from this page https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html#annotation-based-security i can see there is `getSecurityContext()` function, I tried to call it from my `App ` class, but there is no such a method. could you help please ?

Comment: It is explained in chapiter 16.1.1.1. Initializing Security Context with Servlets, it is the servlet container that give the securitycontext, so you need to configure user/profile in the server. This feature is include in Java EE server, but I don't think that is include in tomcat.

Comment: Java EE exemple : http://www.butonic.de/2010/06/18/a-simple-jax-rs-security-context-example-in-glassfish/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your authentication mechanism looks like.

### Java EE Security

If you are relying on the standard Java EE Web application security mechanisms offered by the servlet container, the authentication can be configured via the application's `web.xml` descriptor. It's very likely you will need to define a realm in your container and reference it in your `web.xml` descriptor with the `<real-name>` element. Something like:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/rest/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/rest/orders/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>customer</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>my-default-realm</realm-name>
</login-config>
```

In this approach, **your realm** will tell **the container** whether a user is in a role or not.

To learn more about Java EE Security, have a look at the [Java EE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-intro.htm).

### Custom authentication

On the other hand, when you are performing a custom authentication like the one described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/1426227), you could use a custom implementation of [`SecurityContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/SecurityContext.html). In this situation, you need to authenticate the user manually against your LDAP, database, file, etc.

For a custom authetication, you could use a [`ContainerRequestFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html) like the one show below:

```java
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        // Authenticate the user: How the authentications will be performed is up to you
        // If the authentication failed, abort the request with a 401 status code
        // If the authentication succeeded, you know who your user claims to be

        final SecurityContext securityContext = requestContext.getSecurityContext();
        requestContext.setSecurityContext(new SecurityContext() {

            @Override
            public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
                 return new Principal() {
                    @Override
                    public String getName() {
                        // Return the user name here
                        return null;
                    }
                };
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
                // Return if the user is in a role
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isSecure() {
                return securityContext.isSecure();
            }

            @Override
            public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
                return "Custom";
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How the authentication will be performed is your business. The recommended approach for HTTP authetication is to send the credentials in the `Authorization` header of the request. The [`ContainerRequestContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html) API will give you access to details of the request.

In this approach, **you** need to write the code to determine whether a user is in a role or not.

---

<sup>**Note:** Mind that you won't rely on sessions. The authentication/authorization process must be performed for each request.</sup>

Comment: I am using basic http authentication, in your public String getName()  function, where is the name comes from ? is it the user name the user has send? or what?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli How do you authenticate the users? Show the code.

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli I suppose you let the server manage authentication for you, without code. I think you can implement SecurityContext using HttpServletRequest.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin thanks but please where can I state that **the user name marco** is **admin** role, sounds like my english is so bad that no one is understanding me

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli It could be stated in the database, in a file, hard coded... Do you use Java EE Security or what?

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin okay so whenever any request comes to my server, the code in the AuthenticationFilter will be executed ? right? (appreciate it )

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Yes, the filter will be executed for each request that comes to the server.

Comment: @CássioMazzochiMolin thanks, I put System.out.println("role=" + role); in the isUserInRole function, and nothing was printed, means that function is not being called, though i have this @RolesAllowed({ "admin", "thirdPartyDeveloper" }) in the beginning of my class that has my services. Note that the *filter* is being called, i can see that,  could you help please?

Comment: plus, my friend, you said that i get the username from the database or a file or or or ... but the username is coming in the request, i need to know that username to know if i authenticate it or not, please how can I get that username from the request? your code returns "null" in the method for user name, should I user that *requestContext* instance to extract the username from the headers?