# How to authenticate users in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am writing a RESTful application in Java using Jersey, and i need to authenticate users. I know i can specify the roles in the resource using the annotations @RolesAllowed, but i can't understand how a user is associated to a specific role. The client sends username and password in this way

```
    HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic(user, password);
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    client.register(feature);
    WebTarget target = client.target(baseUrl).path(urlString);
    Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    Response response = invocationBuilder.get();
```

Supposing that some methods can be used only by superusers and others by any user, how can i distinguish them when the username and the password are sent by the client?

Answer (score 11):

> I know i can specify the roles in the resource using the annotations @RolesAllowed, but i can't understand how a user is associated to a specific role

The role information is stored in the DB. Assuming say you have a `User` that models the USER and ROLES table in the DB

```
class User {
  String username;
  List<String> roles;

  public String getUsername() { return username; }
  public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }
  public List<String> getRoles() { return roles; }
  public void setRoles(List<String> roles) { this.roles = roles; }
}
```

You would get the `User` inside a Jersey filter. This is also where you would authenticate.

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHENTICATION)  // needs to happen before authorization
class AuthenticationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Inject
    private UserService userService;  // this is your own service

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContex context) {
        // note, this is a lazy implementation of Basic auth.
        // it doesn't do ant error checking. Please see
        // link at bottom for better imlementation
        String authzHeader = context.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION); // (1)
        String decoded = Base64.decodeAsString(authzHeader);
        String[] split = decoded.split(":");
        User user = userService.getUser(split[0]);                              // (2)
        if (user == null || !user.getPassword().equals(someHash(split[1])) {    // (3)
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        }
        SecurityContext oldContext = context.getSecurityContext();               // (4)
        context.setSecurityContext(new BasicSecurityConext(user, oldContext.isSecure()));
    }
}
```

What you're doing here is:

1. Parsing the Basic Auth Authorization header
2. Getting the `User` with the username
3. Doing your authentication
4. Setting a new `SecurityContext`.

The `BasicSecurityContext` is shown below. This is where you will associate roles with the user.

```
static class BasicSecurityContext implements SecurityContext {
   private final User user;
   private final boolean secure;
   
   public BasicSecurityContext(User user, boolean secure) {
       this.user = user;
       this.secure = secure;
   }

   @Override
   public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
       return new Principal() {
           @Override
           public String getName() {
                return user.getUsername();
           }
       };
   }

   @Override
   public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
       return SecurityContext.BASIC_AUTH;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean isSecure() { return secure; }

   @Override
   public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
       return user.getRoles().contains(role);
   }
}
```

If you look at the bottom at the `isUserInRole`. What will happen is that Jersey will grab the `@RolesAllowed` annotation from the resource method or class, grab the values, then pass them to the `isUserInRole`. If it returns `true`, then the user is authorized. In pseudo-code

```
@GET
@Path("/somepath")
@RolesAllowed({"USER", "SUPER_USER"})
public Response get() {}
...

RolesAllowed annotation = resourceMethod.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
String roles = annotation.value();
SecurityContext context = getSecurityContext();
for (String role: roles) {
    if (context.isUserInRole(role)) {
        return;
    }
}
throw new ForbiddenException();
```

This is just pseudo-code, but it shows how Jersey handles the authorizaiton, using the `@RolesAllowed`, the `SecurityContext`, and how you implement the `isUserInRole`.

This authorization feature is not automatically turned on. You need to turn it on yourself. To do so, simply register the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`

```
public JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {
    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(RolesAllowedDynamicFeature.class);
    }
}
```

One thing to note here is that in all of the above, we are implementing our basic authentication and setting of the security context. There is nothing really wrong with this. But if you are using the servlet container authentication mechanism, Jersey will actually take the auth information from the `HttpServletRequest`. The `HttpServletRequest` has a `getUserPrincipal()` method and a `isUserInRole` method. Jersey will use these to delegate in the `SecurityContext`. So if you *are* user the container authentication, then you don't really need to implement anything. You just need to register the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`

If you want to use your container's authentication mechanism, you should consult your server's documentation. After having set up a realm in with your server, you will then need to configure the `web.xml` with the security information. There's an example in the link below. You should also find this information in the Java EE docs under the web security section.

**See also:**

- [Filter and Interceptors](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) to learn more about working with filters.
- [Security](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/security.html) for a little more info on working with security in Jersey.
- [A better implementation of the basic auth filter](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jersey/blob/master/examples/https-clientserver-grizzly/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/httpsclientservergrizzly/SecurityFilter.java)
- [What exactly is the ResourceConfig class in Jersey 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627178/2587435)

Comment: Thanks! There are two thing i don't understand:
1 - Where can i find the UserService class? Or do i have to implement it?
2 - Where do i have to implement the JerseyConfig class? Who has to instantiate it?

Comment: 1) UserService is your own class you use to grab data from the database. It is just an example. 2)  That is a jersey configuration class. You can use it instead of or along-side with a web.xml. You don't create it. Jersey will create it. You either need to reference it in the web.xml

Comment: See [What exactly is the ResourceConfig class in Jersey 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45627178/2587435)

Answer (score 2):

There are two things we need to address

1. Authentication - Checking if the user is really the one it claims to be
2. Authorization - If the authenticated user has the privilege to access the given method

To do both authentication and authorization, we need a data store that store that stores the following mapping:

1. Mapping between user and its password
2. Mapping between roles and users
3. Mapping between roles and permissions

Here the first mapping is required for authentication and the other two mappings are used for authorization.

Also, note that we need to do authentication and authorization for every API call. So we will be doing a lot of read operations.

Hence, usually a directory server or Ldap server such as Apache DS is used to store these mappings because a directory server is a read optimised data store.

In a RESTful application usually a filter is used to extract the username and password from the request header, and do the authentication with the Ldap server. IF the authenication is successful, the next step is to extract the permissions of the user from the Ldap server by consulting the user-role and role-permission mappings. If the user is authorized, only in that case the control flows to the actual API business logic.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/1235935) answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

HttpAuthenticationFeature class provides HttpBasic and Digest client authentication capabilities. The feature work in one of 4 modes;

**BASIC:** It’s preemptive authentication way i.e. information is send always with each HTTP request. This mode must be combined with usage of SSL/TLS as the password is send only BASE64 encoded.

**BASIC NON-PREEMPTIVE:** It’s non-preemptive authentication way i.e. auth information is added only when server refuses the request with 401 status code and then the request is repeated with authentication information.

**DIGEST:** Http digest authentication. Does not require usage of SSL/TLS.

**UNIVERSAL:** Combination of basic and digest authentication in non-preemptive mode i.e. in case of 401 response, an appropriate authentication is used based on the authentication requested as defined in WWW-Authenticate HTTP header.

To use HttpAuthenticationFeature, build an instance of it and register with client. For example;

1) Basic authentication mode

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basic("username", "password");

final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(feature);
```

2) Basic authentication : non-prempitive mode

```
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.basicBuilder()
                                    .nonPreemptive()
                                    .credentials("username", "password")
                                    .build();

final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(feature);
```

3) Universal mode

```
//Universal builder having different credentials for different schemes
HttpAuthenticationFeature feature = HttpAuthenticationFeature.universalBuilder()
.credentialsForBasic("username1", "password1")
.credentials("username2", "password2").build();

final Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
client.register(feature);
```

Comment: Thanks, but i need to know how to modify the resource to make it understand when a request comes from a superuser or a regular user.