# Adding an annotation to a method to note if it is allowed to run

Tags: java, security, annotations, jersey

I have implemented parts of my own security framework in java and I have run into a small-ish problem.

I want to be able to check if a user has access to a method or not.
I can do this by simply adding a check inside of the method like the following:

```
@GET
public Response getResource() throws Exception
{
    if (AuthUtils.isAuthenticated(request, "ROLE1", "ROLE2"))
        return Response.ok("Hello World!").build();
    else
        return Response.status(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED).build();
}
```

Where you supply a list of roles that are authorized to use the function.

However in an ideal world, I would like to do something like the following

```
@Secure(roles = {"ROLE1", "ROLE"})
@GET
public Response getResource() throws Exception
{
    return Response.ok("Hello World!").build();
}
```

Where it by default returns an unathorized response on all methods annotated with @Secure where the user does not have the correct roles.

Is something like this possible with Java? and if so, how?

Comment: Certainly. That's how most of the ready-made frameworks do it, which you should be using anyway.

Comment: Alright, fair enough. So the million-dollar-question is: How would I implement it?

Comment: With regular annotation processing, but you also need AOP to actually intercept the calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Jersey 2.x, just use the `RolesAllowedDynamicFeature`. You need to register it with your application. This will handle the authorization. You would use the annotation `@RolesAllowed`. It can go at the class level or method level

```
@RolesAllowed({"ROLE1", "ROLE"})
@GET
public Response getResource() throws Exception
```

If you are using Servlet Authentication, then the roles will be populated in the `HttpServletRequest#getUserRoles`. Here you will not need to do anything else. I assume servlet security is what you are using from the looks of this code

```
if (AuthUtils.isAuthenticated(request, "ROLE1", "ROLE2"))
```

I'm guessing the `request` is the `HttpServletRequest`.

If you're not using Servlet security, then to make this work, you need to use a [Jersey filter](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html) to set the `SecurityContext`. Jersey will use the `SecurityContext` to check the roles. You can see an example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42381105/2587435).

**See also:**

- [Jersey Security documentation](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/security.html). If you look in the authorization section, it will explain a bit more about other annotations you can use.

Comment: This sounds really promising. I will try and see if I can implement it

Comment: I had to make some modifications to the examples in the post, but I got it working pretty much exactly how I want it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is make an aspect, ie. a method that gets called every time before a specific "target method" is called. You can use Spring as mentioned before but you can also do this using just Java core and Reflection. To do this, you will need to have a proxy method that calls your actual "target method" only if the user has the right permissions. Alternatively the proxy would throw an exception. So what this means is that you also need to make your dependency injection dynamic.

For a very simple application you don't even need annotations. Say you want to secure the access to the method Service::getSecuredResource :

```
public interface Service {
    Object getSecuredResource();
}

public class ServiceImpl implements Service {
    public Object getSecuredResource() {
        System.out.println("in my secure method");
        return "something private";
    }
}

public class ClientController {
    private Service service;     //line 1

    public void doSomething(){
        service.getSecuredResource();
    }

    public void setService(Service service)...
}

public final class AuthenticationService {

    public static void authenticate()...

    public static boolean isAuthenticated()...//do permission checks here
}
```

A simple solution would be:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ClientController clientController = new ClientController();

        injectDependencies(clientController);

        clientController.doSomething();
    }

    private static void injectDependencies(ClientController clientController) {       //line 2
        final Service serviceProxy = new Service() {
            private Service targetObject = new ServiceImpl();

            public Object getSecuredResource() {
                if (AuthenticationService.isAuthenticated()) {
                    return targetObject.getSecuredResource();
                }
                throw new SecurityException("you're not authorised");
            }
        };

        clientController.setService(serviceProxy);
    }
}
```

Of course, if you want something more dynamic, you will need to have annotations and use Reflection to create dynamic proxies and to inject the dependencies.
I would annotate the service declaration (line 1) with my custom annotation, say `MyInject`.
Then Main::injectDependencies method (line 2) would be replaced by something like this:

```
   private static void injectDependencies(ClientController clientController) {
       Arrays.stream(clientController.getClass().getFields())
               .filter(field -> field.getAnnotation(MyInject.class)!=null)
               .forEach(field -> injectField(field, clientController));
   }

   private static void injectField(Field field, ClientController clientController) {
       InvocationHandler handler = new InvocationHandler() {
           @Override
           public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
               //verify here that the user has the right permissions for the called method
           }
       };
       Service serviceProxy = (Service) Proxy.newProxyInstance(
               Service.class.getClassLoader(),
               new Class[] { Service.class },
               handler);
       clientController.setService(serviceProxy);
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

yes, possible. We can use spring security plugin/library to do this.
In Spring We can follow [Spring security](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security/)
In Grails We can follow [Spring Security Plugin](http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/spring-security-core)

Comment: He wants to create a custom annotation for his own security framework, not use spring security.