# javax.enterprise.event.Event initialization

Tags: java, authentication, jax-rs

Hi I am following this post [Best practice for REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey) to implement a token based authentication system. When I am deploying the services, tomcat is getting started and not getting any error related auto-wiring or other, but when I am hitting a controller, I am not able to fire the event as it is showing null pointer exception for userAuthenticatedEvent. I think the event is not initialized.

```
@Autowired
@AuthenticatedUser
private Event<Long> userAuthenticatedEvent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@Inject` over the declaration. The `Event<T>` class from `javax.enterprise.event` is managed and instantiated automatically by CDI.
When you need to fire the event just use `fire()` passing an argument of type T in it.
eg:

`@Inject`
`@AuthenticatedUser`
`private Event<Long> userAuthenticatedEvent;`

`userAuthenticatedEvent.fire(*some Long value*);`