# How to revoke all the tokens for a user when they change their password with Jersey and OAuth2

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, jersey, token

There is a requirement in our application: 
When users change their password, all other logins (from other devices or computers) should be re-authenticated (except for the current user's session).

I read below (link provided below and cited the paragraph which is relevant) and got the idea: revoke all the tokens for a user.
But Not sure how to implement this (revoke all tokens). We are using Jersey and OAuth2.
Does revoking tokens means remove existing access token/refresh token from session and cookie. Then replace with new tokens?

Thanks

[Best practice for REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey]
[Best practice for REST token-based authentication with JAX-RS and Jersey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey)

> Handling token revocation with JWT
>
> If you want to revoke tokens, you must keep the track of them. You
>   don't need to store the whole token on server side, store only the
>   token identifier (that must be unique) and some metadata if you need.
>   For the token identifier you could use UUID.
>
> The jti claim should be used to store the token identifier on the
>   token. When validating the token, ensure that it has not been revoked
>   by checking the value of the jti claim against the token identifiers
>   you have on server side.
>
> For security purposes, revoke all the tokens for a user when they
>   change their password.

Answer (score 1):

In general (not only with Jersey), you have to invalidate all tokens generated for a user when change their password.

> But Not sure how to implement this (revoke all tokens)

That means that you have to `expire` every issued token in your oauth-server database for that user:

- relational DBs: a batch update.
- noSQL: a single remove of the reference.
- Redis or similiar, a force evict.

> Does revoking tokens means remove existing access token/refresh token from session and cookie. Then replace with new tokens?

Sort of, revoking means:

- expire (not necesary remove) all issued tokens from database.
- the session and cookies must be aware of this and to be removed or marked as expired when you detect it (usually a tricky part).

> Then replace with new tokens?

In most cases, after this, when a user want to access a protected resource, your security filter/layer must:

- redirect to the login page through the oauth2 server (the re-authentication part).
- or return an `access_denied` error (in the case of services, APIs)