# How to implement user login in Jersey API

Tags: rest, api, authentication, jersey

I am implementing RESTful API using javax.ws.rs. The response of the calls that I need to implement requires knowing which user is logged in currently. I tried making a separate call for the user login:

api.myapi.co.uk/authenticate?username=xxxx&password=xxxx

where I basically save the user information is a global variable 
and then tried to make another call to retrieve information from the database based on the user that has been saved earlier but I find the value as null during the second call. What am I missing? Is my approach wrong? do you have any suggestions please?

Comment: You will need to provide some code in order for us to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I see what you are doing. I will add an answer. But in the future, add your code to the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code probably looks like this, right?

```
@Path("/")
public class MyResource{
  private String username;
  private String password;
  @Path("authenticate")
  public String authenticate(@QueryParam("username") username, @QueryParam("password") password) {
    if(!username.equals("zainab") || !password.equals("letmein"))
      return "Incorrect username or password";
    this.username=username;
    this.password=password;
    return "Sucessfully authenticated";
  }
  @Path("secret")
  public String secret() {
    if(username == null || password == null)
      return "Sorry, not authorized";
    return "You are authorized: "+username;
  }
}
```

If so, the problem is that JAX-RS creates a new Resource object for each request. A request to "/secret" then uses a new instance of `MyResource`, which has username and password as null.

Then, you might think, *I'll just make it `static`!* Then, your resource can't handle concurrent requests. What if Person A calls "/authenticate", then "/secret". Then Person B calls "/secret" without authenticating. He can then access "/secret" without authenticating!

Anyways, this violates the idea of RESTful services. The S in RESTful stands for "Stateless". This means that the server should store no state per client, and possibly give the user a token to pass with concurrent requests.

One possibility is to accept the username and password for every request to secret ("`/secret?username=zainab&password=letmein`"). Or you could implement token-based authentication, where the user calls "/authenticate" to get a token, and they pass that token on all later requests. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/2600184) is a link to help with that.

Also, note that username and password is usually not send in the URL as a query param, but instead in the Authorization HTTP header as such `Authorization: base64encode("USERNAME:PASSWORD")`