# Java – custom annotation won't be considered

Tags: java, interface, annotations, jax-rs

I have built an EmployeeEndpoint which holds different methods like create, update, remove, and many more. To simplify this question I only used the create method.

Because I want a scalable application I’ve built an interface that holds the base methods. Within the interface I can now annotate the methods with the JAX-RS-Annotations. Because they will be inherited I only have to override the interface method within EmployeeEndpoint.

**Interface**

```
public interface RESTCollection<T> {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public T create(T entity) throws Exception;
}
```

**Endpoint**

```
@Stateless
@Path(“employee“)
public class EmployeeEndpoint implements RESTCollection<Employee> {
    @Override
    public Employee create(Employee employee) throws Exception {
        return this.createEmployee(employee);
    }
}
```

The example above works fine. If I want to add a custom annotation I can do:

**Solution 1**

```
public interface RESTCollection<T> {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Permissions(Role.Admin)
    public T create(T entity) throws Exception;
}
```

or

**Solution 2**

```
@Stateless
@Path(“employee“)
public class EmployeeEndpoint implements RESTCollection<Employee> {
    @Override
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Permissions(Role.Admin)
    public Employee create(Employee employee) throws Exception {
        return this.createEmployee(employee);
    }
}
```

But solution **1** isn’t a good idea, because not every entity can be created only by an administrator. And with solution **2** I am loosing the advantage of scalability and less code for the annotations. So the best way would be:

**Solution 3**

```
@Stateless
@Path(“employee“)
public class EmployeeEndpoint implements RESTCollection<Employee> {
    @Override
    @Permissions(Role.Admin)
    public Employee create(Employee employee) throws Exception {
        return this.createEmployee(employee);
    }
}
```

But now when I catch the Permissions-Annotation within the JAX-RS' ContainerRequestFilter interface method called filter I get the value of `null` which I don’t understand.

```
@Context
private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

resourceInfo.getResourceMethod().getAnnotation(Permissions.class) // is null
```

**Annotation**

```
@NameBinding
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Permissions {
    Role[] value() default {};
}
```

**Enum**

```
public enum Role {
    Admin,
    User
}
```

Is it possible in any way to go with solution **3** or a different approach where I have the same advantage?

**UPDATE**

Because the reason doesn't seem to be the code I posted I will show you my AuthorizationFilter. Therefore I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey) post.

**AuthorizationFilter**

```
@Provider
@Priority(Priorities.AUTHORIZATION)
public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Inject
    @AuthenticatedUser
    private User authenticatedUser;

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        Class<?> resourceClass = resourceInfo.getResourceClass();
        List<Role> classRoles = extractRoles(resourceClass);

        Method resourceMethod = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
        List<Role> methodRoles = extractRoles(resourceMethod);

        try {

            if (methodRoles.isEmpty()) checkPermissions(classRoles, requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));
            else checkPermissions(methodRoles, requestContext.getHeaderString(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION));

        } catch (NotAuthorizedException e) {
            requestContext.abortWith(
                    Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED).build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            requestContext.abortWith(
                    Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).build());
        }
    }

    private List<Role> extractRoles(AnnotatedElement annotatedElement) {
        if (annotatedElement == null) return new ArrayList<Role>();
        else {
            Permissions perms = annotatedElement.getAnnotation(Permissions.class);
            if (perms == null) return new ArrayList<Role>();
            else {
                Role[] allowedRoles = perms.value();
                return Arrays.asList(allowedRoles);
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkPermissions(List<Role> allowedRoles, String authorizationHeader) throws NotAuthorizedException, Exception {
        if (!allowedRoles.isEmpty()) {
            if (authorizationHeader == null || !authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer "))
                throw new NotAuthorizedException("Authorization header must be provided");
            else if (!allowedRoles.contains(this.authenticatedUser.getRole()))
                throw new Exception("User has no permissions");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the Permission isn’t considered at all"?

Comment: When I catch the Permissions-Annotation within the JAX-RS' ContainerRequestFilter interface method called filter I get the value of `null`.

Comment: Just tested and it works fine. Are you getting a NullPointerException or is the result of the call null?

Comment: The result of the call is null.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good.

I have run a few tests and the only reason I can think of is that you are using **2 different `Permission` types** on your Employee resource than the one on your filter. (check your imports)

Not sure about your `Filter` code, but this is mine which is working (see the imports):

```
package com.app.filters; // TODO change this with yours

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

import com.app.services.Permissions; // TODO change this with yours

public class AuthorizationFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Context
    ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter (ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        Permissions perms   = resourceInfo.getResourceMethod ().getAnnotation (Permissions.class);

        System.out.println (getClass ().getSimpleName () + " --> Permissions: " + Arrays.toString (perms.value ())); // prints [Admin]
    }

}
```

Bonus, if you want to test the actual value of the annotation on your Employee resource:

```
....
import com.app.services.Permissions; // TODO change this with yours (the one on the filter being the same as this one)
....

@Permissions (Role.Admin)
@Override
public Employee create (Employee employee) throws Exception {
    Class<?> [] cArg    = new Class [1];
    cArg [0]            = Employee.class;

    Method method       = getClass ().getMethod ("create", cArg);
    Permissions perms   = method.getAnnotation (Permissions.class);

    System.out.println (EmployeeService.class.getSimpleName () + " --> Permissions: " + Arrays.toString (perms.value ()));

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, but that doesn't explain why solution 1 and 2 work. This is assuming the OP actually tested 1 and 2.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It isn't an import issue and my AuthorizationFilter is pretty similar to yours. But I updated my question and posted the AuthorizationFilter, just in case.