# RESTful authentication on the web-server

Tags: rest, http, authentication, jersey

Previously, I did not have to work with HTTP authentication on the server.
But they gave me an assignment.

### Quotation:

> "We have enough password authentication. While we decided
>   that there will be enough authentication layer between the client
>   (AngularJS) and the Web server (RESTful, Jersey)."

Can you help with advice or suggest literature?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

REST API resources are stateless. It needed to be secure. On every rest call, authentication must happen to ensure right person access these APIs. It does not mean `username` and `password` to be used on the every call.

Industry standard authentication protocols help reduce the effort of securing your API. Custom security protocols can be used, but only under very specific circumstances. [This blogs](https://stormpath.com/blog/secure-your-rest-api-right-way) cover few of the major one like `OAuth1.a`, `OAuth2.1` etc.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey) link explain Token Based Authentication, every thing you need to start securing your APIs