# Does jersey currently support OAuth 2 on server side?

Tags: java, security, oauth, oauth-2.0, jersey

I want to create REST application with jersey and provide its api for other services. Which approach can be used? I found here answers older than 7 years ago.
Maybe does someone know better aproaches?

Comment: Are you trying to create an authz / authn server or validating an authoriation token?

Comment: I haven't got experiance with this technologies, I just need get credentials of user and generate token for work with my api

Comment: @ChrisHinshaw I found ready solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey/26778123#26778123)
but there I need to write issue and filter logic myself. Is it good approach or maybe better solution is using JWT libraries?