# Injecting @RequestScoped variable in singleton in wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, cdi

I've got a Java EE app running in wildfly acting as a REST API. Before an endpoint logic is run, a filter grabs a JWT out of the headers and sets the user on a request scoped variable like the CDI solution proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26778123/4236181

If I then inject that bean in a class annotated with @Singleton and run multiple requests at once I can see that Wildfly is using a single instance of my singleton class as expected, but it seems it's doing proxy magic for my request scope variable. My request scoped variable is different in each request, even though they are using the same instance of the singleton. I was under the impression you could not use request scoped variables in a singleton, does Wildfly allow you to do that now? What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contextual reference to a bean with a normal scope(such as RequestScope), is not a direct reference to a contextual instance of the bean. Instead, the contextual reference is a client proxy object. when a method is called the proxy looks up the current instance.  so you could use RequestScope in a singleton

https://developer.jboss.org/blogs/stuartdouglas/2010/10/12/weld-cdi-and-proxies  this would look sort of like this:(shows a client proxy).

```
public class PaymentProcessor_$$Proxy extends PaymentProcessor  
{  
  public void processPayment(int amount)  
  {  
    PaymentProcessor instance = lookupBean();  
    instance.processPayment(amount);  
  }  

  private PaymentProcessor lookupBean()  
  {  
    //get the correct instance from the BeanManager and return it  
  }  
}
```

As you can see, client proxy gets the correct instance from the BeanManager(lookupBean method)