# Best practice for enabling a user to only change the data he owns on JAX-RS and Jersey

Tags: java, authentication, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey/26778123#26778123) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey/45814178#45814178) are good examples of best practices on dealing with REST token-based authentication.

But in my case I am worried about one user using his own token to modify another user's data. The problem arises when we just verify if a user has a valid token and if positive, then execute any operation the user asked for.

Of course the most simple way to defeat this is to check if the authorized user `id` is the same as the one in the Request JSON (e.g. `user_id`). But this is tedious (all endpoints need this logic) and error prone (we might forget to do it for one endpoint).

Are there any ways to automate this?

Comment: You should be able to able to do what you are suggesting inside of a filter. Have you tried it? Or maybe even AOP.

Comment: I thought a filter, but I am not sure this is the best solution, as if I understand this correctly, all my Requests will have to use the same parameter names, such as `user_id`. If another developer in the project sends his user data as `userId`, the security check would not work. So I wanted to know if there was something more robust out there (I never used AOP before).

Comment: I don't understand your concern about the parameter names and what it would have to do with this. You should try to implement it and see what you come up with.

Comment: Well, I am not very experienced with Jersey, but my objective is to validate a Token and see if the user in the Token is the same user the Request is trying to set some data. So in the filter I will have to get the request parameters, search for any parameters that corresponds to a user id and compare if it's the same ID as the one in the Token. That's why I think I need the exact parameter name.... Or am I missing something?