# Jersey JAX-RS Dependency Injection

Tags: java, kotlin, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to build a REST API using JAX-RS, specifically the Jersey implementation. I tried to implement Authentication like in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777083/best-practice-for-rest-token-based-authentication-with-jax-rs-and-jersey/26778123#26778123).

Basically I'm using a `ContainerRequestFilter` to filter the HTTP Requests, based on the Authorization header. This class defines a property, annotated with the `@Inject` attribute (I'm using Kotlin, not Java):

```
@Inject
var authenticationService: IAuthenticationService? = null
```

I've registered this authentication service in my AbstractBinder:

```
class MyApplicationBinder : AbstractBinder() {
    override fun configure() {
        bind(AuthenticationService::class.java) to IAuthenticationService::class.java
    }
}
```

and registering this application binder to my `ResourceConfig`:

```
class MyResourceConfig : ResourceConfig() {
    init {
        // ...
        register(MyApplicationBinder())
    }
}
```

However I'm getting the runtime exception on startup:

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
    There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(
        requiredType=IAuthenticationService,
        parent=AuthenticationRequestFilter,
        qualifiers={},
        position=-1,
        optional=false,
        self=false,
        unqualified=null,
        452444366
    )
```

I have no idea why the registration in my AbstractBinder is ignored by the HK2 Container! Can someone please help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a minimal GitHub project we can test?